# Issue using Gmaps.js in site with twitter bootstrap. Zoom buttons not appearing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, google-maps, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using gmaps.js to create map in a site based on twitter bootstrap and the google maps zoom in/ zoom out buttons don't appear. Also I noticed when you click the marker the 'x' close button doesn't appear. Here is the link to the page.

http://www.smileconnectcard.co.uk/FindPractice/SearchResults?location=London%2C%20UK

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue with Bootstrap that conflicts with google maps api.  The issue applies `max-width:100%` to all images.  This is acceptable in most cases, but it causes a conflict with google api.

There have been various attempts to fix this and various reverts by the bootstrap developers - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1552.

To fix this so that it only affects the google map I would recomend using the following css

```
#map label { width: auto; display:inline; }
#map img { max-width: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

On inspecting, `img` tag has `max-width: 100%`

So try this, it is working.

```
img {
max-width: none;
}
```

Maybe happened due to **CSS Conflict**.

**Update:** As I suspected, **`it is a CSS Conflict.`**

it happened because of your **`layout.css`**

```
img {
    max-width:100%;  // change it here
}
```

Comment: @user2525027 That what I mean and given as answer right.  In my updates I've used max-`width:100%;  // change it here`.  No prob(change it here means it has to be done here) yet want to give you an update :)